# i get error when trying to install firebase at angular project

Tags: angular, firebase, npm, webpack, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to install firebase in my angular project but i got error this what i write to install

npm install firebase @angular/fire --save

PS D:\work\frontend\Angular\market> npm install firebase @angular/fire --save
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...HJOQNa7GdSHtCc6vY1COf'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-11-21T22_48_16_343Z-debug.log

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KODlH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using node.js as your back-end then the issue might be related to a cache clear error that is preventing the json data files from being parsed and therefore necessary files are missing from the installation process.[1]

Attempt the following solutions:

- Execute the following command “npm cache clean --force”
- Completely uninstall Node.js from “Programs and Features” and
  re-install. Make sure all the node-modules and npm caches are deleted
  in the NPM folder
- Clear your npm cache folder, the default location is here:
  C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\

[1] https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/990